# Priority queue in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am implementing a queueing system with multiple priorities.
I would like a query which can return X rows with **at least** Y rows of each priority.

For example:

Lets say the queue has 3 priorities (High, Medium and Low), and I would like 3, 2 and 1 rows for each priority respectively.

If the table looked like this:

```
-----------------
| Id | Priority |
-----------------
|  1 |     High |
|  2 |     High |
|  3 |     High |
|  4 |     High |
|  5 |   Medium |
|  6 |   Medium |
|  7 |      Low |
-----------------
```

Three simple queries unioned would return (1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7).

```
SELECT TOP 3 Id FROM tbl WHERE Priority = 'High' UNION
SELECT TOP 2 Id FROM tbl WHERE Priority = 'Medium' UNION
SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM tbl WHERE Priority = 'Low'
```

However a problem occurs when the table doesn't contain enough of a particular priority:

```
-----------------
| Id | Priority |
-----------------
|  1 |     High |
|  2 |     High |
|  3 |     High |
|  4 |     High |
|  5 |   Medium |
|  6 |      Low |
|  7 |      Low |
-----------------
```

I would like to have it return (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).
Using the highest priority to fill in the gaps (in this case, using the 4th High row as there is not enough Mediums).

Is there a query which would accommodate this, or would I be better filtering inside my application rather than at the SQL level?

Comment: Will you always want 3, 2, 1 respectively, or will this be parameterized in some way?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The quantities will be static (not necessarily 3, 2, 1), so no need to have them as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a stored procedure that does this in a for loop (3 times, one for each priority, starting with the lowest) and, at each iteration, dynamically adjust the number of values to be returned in the next iteration (higher priority) if there are not enough in this one.

With **dynamically** I mean:

```
SELECT TOP (@count) * FROM SomeTable
```

where `count` was adjusted if necessary in the previous iteration.

The problem with having it in the application logic is that you would either have to fetch more data (3 times the maximum counter used in `TOP`) such that you can have enough data to fill your slots, or you have to communicate with your DB again.

For small numbers, preventive extra fetching is not important. My preference would be to have it in a stored procedure.

But there are a number of variables that play a role here: size of individual rows you fetch, size of the table you search in and its indexes, you program architecture, network configuration, counter values, number of priorities, etc., etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on SQL Server 2005 or higher, a combination of nested `CTE`s and ranking functions should be able to do the trick:

```
;with A as 
(
select top 3 * from tbl where priority = 'High'
),
A1 as 
(
select id, priority from (
select * from A
union all
select top 2 id, priority from (select *,
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by case when priority = 'Medium' then 1 else 2 end) as ranker
from tbl where priority in ('High', 'Medium') and id
not in (select id from A))Z order by ranker asc
) X
),
A2 as (
select id, priority from (
select * from A1
union all
select top 1 id, priority from (select *, 
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by case when priority = 'Low' then 1 else 2 end) as ranker
from tbl where priority in ('High', 'Low') and id
not in (select id from A1))Z order by ranker asc
) X
)
select * from A2
order by id
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will get you up to 3 low priority, up to 6 medium priority, and up to 9 high priority. If there aren't enough lower priority items to fill up the queue, the next highest priority is used.

```
;WITH PriorityRanks AS (
  SELECT
    ID,
    Priority,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Priority ORDER BY ID ASC) as [Rank]
  FROM PriorityQueue
)
, LowPriority AS (
  SELECT
    ID,
    Priority,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) as [Rank]
  FROM PriorityRanks
  WHERE Priority = 'Low'
    AND [Rank] <= 3
)
, MediumPriority AS (
  SELECT
    ID,
    Priority,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) as [Rank]
  FROM PriorityRanks pq
  WHERE pq.Priority = 'Medium'
    AND [Rank] <= 6
      - (SELECT ISNULL(MAX([Rank]), 0) FROM LowPriority)
)
, HighPriority AS (
    SELECT
      ID,
      Priority
    FROM PriorityRanks pq
    WHERE pq.Priority = 'High'
      AND [Rank] <= 9
        - (SELECT ISNULL(MAX([Rank]), 0) FROM LowPriority)
        - (SELECT ISNULL(MAX([Rank]), 0) FROM MediumPriority)
)
SELECT ID, Priority FROM LowPriority
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Priority FROM MediumPriority
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Priority FROM HighPriority
```

Edit: Sorry, I just noticed you wanted the highest priority to fill in the blanks. Shouldn't be too hard to modify, but if you have issues leave a comment and I'll help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone with a CTE based approach, where hopefully each step shows the thought process I was following:

```
declare @t table (Id int not null, Priority varchar(6) not null)
insert into @t (Id,Priority) values
(1,'High'),
(2,'High'),
(3,'High'),
(4,'High'),
(5,'Medium'),
(6,'Low'),
(7,'Low')

--We want 6 rows. We'd like to get 1 low, if available, and 2 mediums, if available
; with NumberedRows as (
    select
        Id,Priority,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Priority ORDER BY Id) as rn,
        CASE Priority WHEN 'High' then 1 WHEN 'Medium' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END as NumPri
    from @t
), Selection as (
    select Id, Priority, NumPri,
        CASE
            WHEN NumPri = 3 and rn <= 1 THEN 1
            WHEN NumPri = 2 and rn <= 2 THEN 2
            WHEN NumPri = 1 THEN 3
            WHEN NumPri = 2 THEN 4
            ELSE 5 --Low, rn>1
        END as Preference
    from NumberedRows
), Chosen as (
    select top 6 * from Selection order by Preference
)
select * from Chosen order by NumPri,Id
```

(On a side note, note that the sample data at the top of my code takes about as much formatting as the table in your question - but it's actually usable in a script)

If the number of items to select varies, then you'd need to change:

```
WHEN NumPri = 3 and rn <= 1 THEN 1
WHEN NumPri = 2 and rn <= 2 THEN 2
```

(Change the `rn` values) and:

```
select top 6 * from Selection order by Preference
```

(Change it to however many are wanted in total)

Note, also, that it doesn't matter that you said you want 3 high priority items - that doesn't matter, since high priority items are used as the fillers if not enough lower priority values can be located.